# Setup aliases on Windows 7 using doskey to call .py file

Tags: python, alias, doskey

I have a global .py file which need to be run from my project directory.

```
python C:\path\to\global_python.py param1
```

Because of the path to .py file is quite long, so I'm trying to set alias using doskey.

I have successfully setup aliases as below examples

```
subl="C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" $*
python="C:\Python27\python.exe" $*
pip="C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe" $*
```

So I have tried to setup an alias for my global .py file.

```
bower_setup="C:\Users\Admin\Documents\home_www\bower\bower_setup.py"
```

I tried to execute it, using `python bower_setup param1` but it was not working.

[image]

Please help me fix this problem, if possible I prefer not to set the windows system path variable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to alias as follows:

```
set subl="C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe"
```

When you are using, you should use as

```
 %subl%
```

for example,

```
 echo %subl%
```

echoes "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe"

Comment: It's not about Sublime, I'm asking about **executing** .py file from other path which is not current working directory.

Comment: i have taken sublime as example, sameway you have to set for other 2 variables and access with %% while using.

Comment: I have tried `set bower_setup="C:\Users\Admin\Documents\home_www\bower\bower_setup.py"` as you suggested, it was not working, quite surprise `echo %bower_setup%` returns **%bower_setup%** instead of **bower_setup**

Comment: it works in my machine..can you try "set "bower_setup=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\home_www\bower\bower_setup.py"" and access using %bower_setup%